# Django - Image gets uploaded after every save()

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a custom upload path for any users avatar. I call a function to set the upload path to `"avatar/" + str(self.username) + "/" + filename`. My problem is everytime the user change e.g. email and save changes, the avatar gets saved again with the same upload path.
models.py

```
def _upload_path(instance, filename):
    return instance.get_upload_path(filename)


def reduce_image_size(avatar):
    img = Image.open(avatar).convert('RGB')
    thumb_io = BytesIO()
    img.save(thumb_io, 'jpeg', quality=50)
    new_image = File(thumb_io, name=avatar.name)
    return new_image


class User(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=_upload_path, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_upload_path(self, filename):
        return "avatar/" + str(self.username) + "/" + filename

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_image = reduce_image_size(self.avatar)
        self.avatar = new_image
```

When first upload image the url is **/media/avatar/username/the_uploaded_image.jpg** and after updating any value it changes to **/media/avatar/username/avatar/username/the_uploaded_image.jpg**

I tried to check if a path already exsist but it wasnt working.

```
    if self.avatar and not os.path.exists(settings.MEDIA_URL + self.get_upload_path(self.avatar.name)):
        new_image = reduce_image_size(self.avatar)
        self.avatar = new_image
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if self.avatar and not os.path.exists(settings.MEDIA_URL + self.get_upload_path(self.avatar.name)):
```

to

```
if not self.pk:
```

it checks if primary key exsits and should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Note that `save` function triggers on every save - both for new and old user.

Thus, `reduce_image_size` is triggered on each save (no matter it is new or old one) - so the image resaved each time.

To make it happen only for new users - simply add the following condition to check if you are working with existing one:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:  # new user
            new_image = reduce_image_size(self.avatar)
            self.avatar = new_image

        super().save(*args, **kwargs) # don't see this line in your code but I guess it's there...
```